# Windows custom Credential Provider

Tags: windows, visual-c++, credential-providers

Working on a custom credential provider which authenticates the user based on the response from a server. If the server or a third party responds with a yes, the CP should allows the user to login without any further authentication but I couldn't find a way to avoid the user authentication. Can we avoid the authentication and allow the user to login based on the response from another server ?

I am trying it on Windows 10. Developing using VC++.

Thanks, Shan.

Comment: To perform a windows login, you would still need the windows password. If you get the user's windows password after server authentication (possibly stored or retrieved from server), then you can populate the field and authenticate without prompting the user again

Comment: Thanks @Wander3r for your response

Comment: The credential providers are only concerned with gathering details for authentication. These details are passed through to the LSA and processed according to the authentication package specified when serializing the credentials (Kerberos or msv1_0). In theory, you could create your own authentication package, but I have never seen any samples for this. You best bet is to ask the user for their password the first time they authenticate, store it securely using some kind of public key-based encryption scheme, and replay it on subsequent login attempts.